# For which $a$ is this function increasing? $ f(x) = \left( \frac {a-2}{a-4}\right) ^{-x} $

Tags: functions

For which $a$ is this function increasing?
$$  f(x) = \left( \frac {a-2}{a-4}\right) ^{-x} $$

So first I would rewrite this as:
$$  f(x) = \left( \frac {a-4}{a-2}\right) ^{x} $$

I was thinking that in order for the function to be increasing the whole fraction has to be bigger than $1$ or smaller than $-1$

So I devided that into two conditions:
$   \frac {a-4}{a-2}> 1 $ and $   \frac {a-4}{a-2} < -1 $

I solved both inequalities and the result should be:
for the first inequality: $(   -\infty, 2) $
fot the other one:  $( 2, 3) $

ANd now for the final  result I should combine both so that would be $K =\left\{( -\infty, 2) U ( 2, 3) \right\} $

Is this corrrect? I have no idea how else I should find out .. But my intuition tells me that something is not correct ..

Thanks for help

Comment: Hello - your argument is sound. However, if $\frac{a-4}{a-2} < -1$, then your function is only defined for integer $x$, not for general $x$. For example if $a = \frac{5}{2}$ and $x = \frac{1}{2}$, then $f(x)$ would have to be $\sqrt{-3}$. Stick with the requirement $\frac{a-4}{a-2} > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @Hans, an exponential function is only defined, if the base is positive. And is increasing if the base is greater than $1.$

Thus we solve 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac {a-4}{a-2}&>1\\
\frac{a-4}{a-2}-1&>0\\
\frac{-2}{a-2}&>0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Since the numerator is negative, this is only possible if the denominator $a-2<0.$ 
The set of solutions is  $K =( -\infty, 2).$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {a-4}{a-2}> 1$ is true for all $a<2$

$\frac {a-4}{a-2}<-1$ is true for all $a\in(2,3)$ but not for all real $x$ - consider $x=\frac12$